# bubble sort linked list not sorting

Tags: c++, linked-list, logic, bubble-sort

Why won't my bubble sort algorithm sort the linked list?
When given a list,  and calling the method, it will output the same list. What's wrong with my current logic inside my for loop?

```
private:
    IntNode *head, *tail;
```

node structure:

```
struct IntNode
{
    int data;
    IntNode * next;
};
```

bubble sort method:

```
void NodeSLList::SortList()
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return;

    IntNode * current = head;
    IntNode * nextElement = current->next;
    IntNode * temp = NULL;

    int changed = 1;


    while (changed)
    {
        changed = 0;
        for (current; (current != NULL) && (nextElement = NULL); )
        {
            if (current->data > nextElement->data)
            {
                temp = current->next;
                current->next = nextElement->next;
                nextElement->next = temp;
                changed = 1;
            }
            current = current->next;
            nextElement = nextElement->next;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems to be the assignment operator: `nextElement = NULL`

Comment: Replace the content of `if` with `std::swap(current->data, nextElement->data)`, it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by assigning in the for-loop, instead of comparing.

If you are implementing a linked list, may I suggest using a sentry, instead of a head 
and NULL as end. This removes all 'corner-cases' during inserts and removes. 
A sentry-node always exists, contains no data, points to the first item, 
and the last item points to it.

May I also suggest using `Mergesort`, it works well for linked list, running in O(NlogN), 
and having no space overhead. You can find an implementation [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through a debugger. If you look at the value of `current` on the second time round the `changed` loop, you will see that `current` is still `null`, so the second time round the `changed` loop it will not go through the `current` loop.